# iPhone Xcode Programming for 10000 data

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I am from Hong Kong and new in iphone programming. I know the basics of Objective-C.
Now, I want to write an iOS app with about 10000 data, each item storing different information, e.g., item number,, name, color, size, etc.

For example:

> Item 1 Apple Red Fruit 2, 100
>   Item 2 Orange Orange Fruit 3, 200
>   Item 3 Pork Pink Meat 3, 300
>   Item 4 .......
>   ...
>   Item 10000 ....

In the past if I wrote programme in desktop (PC), I would store these data in 
a text file (.txt) and read and write all these 10000 data to a array and then do 
some sorting, calcualtion etc. No memory problem and the programme run
quite fast too.

However, I know that because iphone memory is limited. I have the following questions :

1. If I use text file to store these 10000 data and then pass these
   data to an array, will error be occured in iphone? or any memory problem?
2. Is Core Data my best alternative? Can I do sorting, searching etc. from Core Data
3. Is Core Data a good choice in my case?

Answer (score 1):

> If I use text file to store these 10000 data and then pass these data to an array, will error be occured in iphone? or any memory problem?

Yes, the application may be terminated because of memory warning. If you read 10000 file and then you will try to put it to single `NSArray` object, it can have bad consequences.

> Is Core Data my best alternative? Can I do sorting, searching etc. from Core Data

Yes. There are many sorting and searching methods with Core Data. Read [**NSFetchRequest Class Reference**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html) for more info.

> Is Core Data a good choice in my case?

Definetly **yes**. There is no installation or storing problems, because it's built-in into iOS. See [**Core Data Programming Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) for more information about building an application using this powerful framework.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to store you data in a sqlite database although core data is a possibility as well.  Included a couple relevant links to get you going.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/902/sqlite-101-for-iphone-developers-creating-and-scripting

http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started